# PHP Closure Object

Tags: php, object, closures

I am trying to generate lat and long cordinates for about a 1000+ locations, I know how to get them in a range and everything but I was wondering if I can do something like this.

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $lat = function () {
        $float = rand(0, 99999) / 99999;
        $lat = rand(30, 32);
        $lat = $lat + $float;
        return $lat;
    };
    $long = function () {
        $float = rand(0, 99999) / 99999;
        $long = rand(74, 76);
        $long = $long + $float;
        return $long;
    };
    print_r($lat);
}
```

The code didn't throw the desired result instead, I'm getting

```
closureObject()
```

There's no error but I can't seem to get it to work, any help would be wonderful, I've tried reading the documentation but doesn't explain anything related to this.

Can this work?

Comment: Well, what output _did_ you expect if you `print_r()` a function definition, so a closure object?

Comment: Define the closures outside of the loop, and *call* them inside. As it is, you're not really doing anything.

Comment: Remember, a closure is a function - you need to call it to get a value. And if all you're doing in the code above is generating random numbers, why bother with a closure at all?

Comment: You aren't using the closures, you just defined them. Try: `print_r($lat());` and you should see the result. As others have mentioned, why not just define 2 functions then use those functions in your loop? (Could even be 1 function if you see the pattern in them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually call the Closure function you defined like: `echo $lat();` If that is what you are trying to do.

As others have mentioned you could define a function the traditional php way. Something like:

```
function getCoord($min, $max) {
    $float = rand(0, 99999) / 99999;
    $coord = rand($min, $max);
    $coord = $coord + $float;
    return $coord;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo "Lat: " . getCoord(30, 32) . " Long: " . getCoord(74, 76);
}
```

Comment: It's an object, echo only works with strings. I've tried it.

Comment: Yes, `$lat` is a Closure which is an object that is callable. So when you execute: `$lat();` it will return a random float value. Notice how I added `()`to the end of the variable?

Comment: I know about the tradition function, I was wondering if this can work.

Comment: It does work, open up your code and instead of `print_r($lat);` try: `print_r($lat());` Again notice the added parentheses[?](http://67.media.tumblr.com/db649f4441940d7fcbbc2bd5d6646bc1/tumblr_mlj0syTLbP1rf1e3ro1_250.gif)

Answer (score 1):

A [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) is an object that can be called like a function. As you can see from the output, when you use `$lat` in `print_r($lat);`, it is not the result of calling the closure, it is the closure object itself. (Defined by `$lat = function () {...` - see example 2 in the [PHP documentation for anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)), . If you want to get that result, you have to call it with `()`, just like any normal function call.

```
print_r($lat());
```

As it is currently, the closures aren't really necessary, but for an example of how to define and use a closure, you could do like this to eliminate the repeated code:

```
// assign the anonymous function to $coord
$coord = function($a, $b) {
    $float = rand(0, 99999) / 99999;
    $coord = rand($a, $b);
    return $coord + $float;
};

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    // use $coord to generate coordinates for a point
    $point = [$coord(30, 32), $coord(74, 76)];
    var_dump($point);
}
```